# Asterisk has not any reaction digit pressing

Tags: asterisk, agi

I use phpagi extension for asterisk call. In some phone I press digit and get result. But in some phones I press digit but was being result=-1. So, failure result. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You have check dtmfmode on your phone and in asterisk settings and insure it is SAME.

Comment: dtmfmode is auto in my sip.conf. But we use bulk call, so we can not check all of phones.

Comment: auto=inband+rtf2833. So you have check on non-working phone(or on did providers if issue when calling did from PSTN) that they use any one of that. Sorry, no way fix if you can't check phone.

Comment: but it is being randomly. sometime I can get result,  some time I can't get. not orderly

Comment: If so, very likly you use inband and compressed codec(which not work with inband). Anyway, there are no golden bullet for this issue. I already described all.